# How can I update a custom property on a Drive file in a way that is safe from concurrent updates?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am developing a script using Google Apps Script that will allow multiple users to append lines to a regular .csv file stored in Google Drive, as there is no native append functionality in the Drive API.  (It's quite mobile-unfriendly to require the client to retrieve the entire file and then upload it again just to add a single row at the end.)

The script performs a fairly simple operation:

1. Retrieve the file content using `Drive.Files.get()`.
2. Append the new line to the file content.
3. Save the new version of the file using `Drive.Files.update()`.

In order to avoid the "lost update" problem during concurrent append operations by multiple users, the script will need to acquire a mutual exclusion lock before performing steps #1-3.  For scalability reasons (imagine that this script is being offered as a hosted service and that there are many thousands of users) the lock needs to be scoped to the individual file;  therefore I won't be able to use the built-in `LockService` because it doesn't offer a lock with the correct scope.

Therefore I am trying to use a (private) custom property that my script can set on the Drive file to indicate that it is currently performing an append operation on that file.  I need to do a read-modify-write sequence on the property, as documented in ["Using patch in a read-modify-write cycle"](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/performance).  When making the update/patch request I need to supply an `If-Match` header with the ETag value from the `Drive.Properties.get()` request, and the update request will be rejected if the property's ETag no longer matches;  this indicates that another script has already updated the property.

How can I accomplish this in Google Apps Script?  According to the auto-completion in the script editor, the `Drive.Properties` object has the following methods:

```
patch(Property resource, String fileId, String propertyKey) : Property
patch(Property resource, String fileId, String propertyKey, Object optionalArgs) : Property
```

I've tried various ways to provide the ETag when calling the `patch()` method, but nothing is working.  None of the following will work:

1. Adding an `etag` property to the `resource` object.
2. Adding an `If-Match` property to the `resource` object.
3. Appending the ETag to the `fileId` or the `propertyKey` values.
4. Adding an `etag` property to the `optionalArgs` object.
5. Adding an `If-Match` property to the `optionalArgs` object.

What is the proper way to make this call?  Unfortunately the Google Apps Script documentation for the Advanced Drive Service lacks any information on how to handle ETag values.

Comment: Apps script contains the Lock Service which prevent concurrent access to sections of code. Check this documentation if helps in your use case. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the three kinds of locks will work for my use case.  (I am trying to co-ordinate access amongst multiple users to a "normal" file in Drive.)

Comment: If you use the ScriptLock to lock the part of the code that reads/writes to the file, according to the documentation, it would make that part of the code accessible only for one user at a time. Why that approach is not working for your use case? Do you also want to "lock" the file for users trying to modify it outside the app?

Comment: as he explained in the question, that won't work because it locks the entire app for all callers thus wont scale.

Comment: Yes, Zig is right:  if 1,000 users are using this script with perhaps 100 different files, each time I use the ScriptLock for user #1 with file A, the other 999 users will be blocked -- even if they want to append to file B or C.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt youll get it working. even if you do, its super innecifient to download the entire file just for append. worse it requires many extra calls to hack the lock in there.

instead, simply keep the data in a spreadsheet per json. spreadsheet api has an efficient appendRow which is guaranteed to work with multiple simultaneous appends.
then simply have a service that builds the json on demand based on the spreadsheet rows.

will work great as long as json reads are few compared to json appends.

Comment: Unfortunately a Google spreadsheet file comes with a lot of "excess baggage".  In this case I'd like to keep the data in a file which doesn't allow users to bypass my app and edit the data directly.  As far as I'm aware, there is no way to create a Google spreadsheet that allows access via the API but doesn't allow users to open it in the Drive UI.

Comment: thats the same issue you already have by storing in drive. the user can go in drive and delete it etc.

Comment: Well yes, of course the owner of the Drive file can do things like delete it or overwrite it...  but at least I wouldn't have to worry about them opening the file in Sheets and mucking around inside, potentially corrupting the data without even meaning to...

Comment: Also, just saw a new issue ["appendRow() does not prevent two scripts writing into the same row"](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5540) posted today in the Apps Script issue tracker...

Comment: hmm that's new and seems like a bug. years ago it did work.